# How DataFrame API depends on RDDs in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Some sources, like [this Keynote: Spark 2.0 talk](https://youtu.be/L029ZNBG7bk?t=598) by Mathei Zaharia, mention that Spark DataFrames are built on top of RDDs. I have found some mentions on RDDs in the [DataFrame](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-1.6/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame.scala) class (in Spark 2.0 I'd have to look at DataSet); but still I have very limited understanding of how these two APIs are bound together behind the scenes.

Can someone explain how DataFrames extend RDDs if they do?

Comment: I highly recommend you read this [slides](http://www.slideshare.net/databricks/building-a-modern-application-with-dataframes-52776940)

Comment: @Umberto, which particular slides do you refer to?

Comment: from slide 60 "Dataframe: Under The Hood"

Comment: @Umberto, thanks! That explains everything very clearly.

Comment: @UmbertoGriffo Hi! :( the slide was deleted... Any other link to it? Thank you

Comment: @Farah Yes the slide was deleted and I haven't another link. Try to read https://medium.com/@kashifmin/spark-sql-whats-happening-under-the-hood-c703d7f5acf5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the DataBricks article [Deep Dive into Spark SQL’s Catalyst Optimizer](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/04/13/deep-dive-into-spark-sqls-catalyst-optimizer.html) (see Using Catalyst in Spark SQL), RDDs are elements of a Physical Plan built by Catalyst. So, we describe queries in terms of DataFrames, but in the end, Spark operates on RDDs.

[image: Catalyst workflow]

Also, you can view the Physical plan of your query by using `EXPLAIN` instruction.

```
//  Prints the physical plan to the console for debugging purpose
auction.select("auctionid").distinct.explain()

// == Physical Plan ==
// Distinct false
// Exchange (HashPartitioning [auctionid#0], 200)
//  Distinct true
//   Project [auctionid#0]
 //   PhysicalRDD   //[auctionid#0,bid#1,bidtime#2,bidder#3,bidderrate#4,openbid#5,price#6,item#7,daystolive#8], MapPartitionsRDD[11] at mapPartitions at ExistingRDD.scala:37
```